# MySQL command - bug with dates

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am trying to put together the following MySqlCommand.

```
string cols = "(DateTime, Ticker, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, ReqCode, UpdateTime)"; 
string parametrs = "(?DateTime, ?Ticker, ?Open, ?High, ?Low, ?Close, ?Volume, ?ReqCode, ?UpdateTime)"; //, ?UpdateTime)";

try {
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = myConn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + schema + cols + " VALUES" + parametrs + "\n ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ReqCode = ?ReqCode AND UpdateTime = ?UpdateTime";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?DateTime", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = aPriceBar.BarTimestamp;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Ticker", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = aPriceBar.Ticker;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Open", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = aPriceBar.Open;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?High", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = aPriceBar.High;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Low", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = aPriceBar.Low;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Close", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = aPriceBar.Close;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Volume", MySqlDbType.UInt32).Value = aPriceBar.Volume;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?ReqCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = aPriceBar.ReqCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?UpdateTime", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = aPriceBar.ReqTimestamp;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} catch (MySqlException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

When I run the program, I catch the following exception:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... for the right syntax to use
>   near ''2013-10-28 16:23:26.379'

I know for sure that 2013-10-28 is the date in ReqTimestamp.

I am surprised because the INSERT query goes through when I do not add to the query a reference to the UpdateTime column: the query uses successfully the DateTime type with one other column (Datetime). However, a) aPriceBar.ReqTimestamp is a DateTime, where reqTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow while b) aPriceBar.BarTimestamp has been generated by

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(sFields[0], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

''2013-10-28 16:23:26.379': the ".379" after the day make me suspect that when I use UctNow, instead of ParseExactsome with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, some timezone information is added to the DateTime instance.

I checked the table definition with MySQL workbench and it looks allright.

Not sure how to fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: You have a column (the last one) named `?UpdateTime`? Do you mean ` UpdateTime` or it is just a typo?

Comment: What are you using '?' to denote your parameters instead of the expected '@'?  Or are the columns `nullable`?

Comment: Set a break point, what's the actual command text look like? I bet it's what Steve said where you have `?UpdateTime` in your `cols` string on line 1.

Comment: @Steve: just a typo on the stackoverflow copy-paste, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @sab669: at the breakpoint I see the CommandText which looks fine. Is there a way to see the actual SQL query when the parameters are replaced with actual values?

Comment: @Brian: Replaced '?' with '@' but that did not help either. By the way, what is the difference between '?' and '@' ? Thanks!

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis - In general, using '?' denotes to the IDE that your type is [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.90).aspx) and using '@' defines a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

if your db field is "datetime" instead of datetime2 /offset it could be a problem with the xxx:xxx.379 part.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The problem is actually with the SQL query syntax.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + schema + cols + " VALUES" + parametrs + "\n ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ReqCode = ?ReqCode AND UpdateTime = ?UpdateTime";
```

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does not support AND but requires a comma instead (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + schema + cols + " VALUES" + parametrs + "\n ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ReqCode = ?ReqCode , UpdateTime = ?UpdateTime";
```

I did not figure it out earlier because I have not yet found a way to see the final query string and check how the placeholders are replaced by the parameters in the query.

Thank you all for your help.